# SSRS 2008 R2 Goto URL Action Mail to field

Tags: url, reporting-services, outlook, action, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a goto url action in Reporting Services 2008 R2 tablix with the expression:

```
="mailto:" & ReportItems!Textbox17.Value &
 "?subject=" & "Project" & Fields!ReferenceNo.Value & "&body=" & "Hi Guys!,"
```

The `ReportItems!Textbox.17.Value` doesn't seem to return the value for the `To` box in the email.

The `ReportItems!Textbox17.Value` is an expression of

```
=Join(
      Lookupset(Fields!ReferenceNo.Value,
      Fields!ReferenceNo.Value,Fields!Task_Owner.Value, "Alert_TaskOwners"),
";")
```

Is it possible to return this value for the "To:" field?
The "To" mail field should return such as:

```
"Name1; Name2; Name2"
```

Comment: Are you using the expression in the same tablix where Textbox17 lives?

Comment: Yes, the expression lives in the same tablix. I hide this column with the value in of "=Join(Lookupset(Fields!ReferenceNo.Value,Fields!ReferenceNo.Value,Fields!Task_Owner.Value, "Alert_TaskOwners"),";")"

Comment: Can you not just put the `join` in your `go to url` expression?

Comment: Yes I have also tried to create the mail goto message such as: ="mailto:" & =Join(
      Lookupset(Fields!ReferenceNo.Value,
      Fields!ReferenceNo.Value,Fields!Task_Owner.Value, "Alert_TaskOwners"),
";")
 &
 "?subject=" & "Project" & Fields!ReferenceNo.Value & "&body=" & "Hi Guys!,"
  .....but does not work.

Comment: The Join expression works as this is displayed in the tablix as Textbox17.Value is exactly what I need when running the report. But transferring the exact text displayed into the email message seems not to work when in the mailto expression.

Comment: @wodz, remove the `=` before the JOIN, leaving:  `="mailto:" & Join( Lookupset(Fields!ReferenceNo.Value, Fields!ReferenceNo.Value,Fields!Task_Owner.Value, "Alert_TaskOwners"), ";") & "?subject=" & "Project" & Fields!ReferenceNo.Value & "&body=" & "Hi Guys!," `

Comment: I receive this error Warning 2 [rsInvalidURLProtocol] The value ‘mailto:Name1;Name2;Name3;Name4;Name5;Name6?subject=Project 10415&body=Hi Guys!,  of the Hyperlink property of the text box ‘Textbox57’ has an invalid schema.  URLs in reports may only use http://, https://, ftp://, mailto: or news:

Comment: So it seems to know what I want it to do as it lists it exactly in the warning but says its invalid?

Comment: @alejandrozuleta yes the = was removed when in the mail to. Still no joy.

Comment: @wodz, It seems report viewer cannot interpret multiple recipients in mailto url. A workaround to this could be create an alias that points to the needed recipients so when you send a mail to that alias the recipients will receive a copy too. Also you could create a group but that would be unnecesary if you can set aliases in your mail service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems that this works by starting the expression with ="mailto://" & ReportItems!Textbox19.Value . . .

the lookup doesn't work but fetching the report item from the tablix with the lookup values in does!